# Building a Native Client app from nothing

Tags: c++, scons, google-nativeclient

What does it take to build a Native Client app from scratch? I have looked into the documentation, and fiddled with several apps, however, I am now moving onto making my own app and I don't see anything related to creating the foundation of a native client app.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depending on the version of the SDK you want to use, you have a couple of options.

**Pepper 16 and 17: use init_project.py or use an example as a starting point**

If you are using `pepper_16` or `pepper_17`, you will find a Python script `init_project.py` in the `project_templates` in the SDK. It will setup up a complete set of files (.cc, .html, .nmf) with comments indicating where you need to add code. Run `python init_project.py  -h` to see what options it accepts. Additional documentation can be found at https://developers.google.com/native-client/pepper17/devguide/tutorial.

**Pepper 18 and newer: use an example as the starting point**

If you are using `pepper_18` or newer, `init_project.py` is no longer included. Instead you can copy a very small example from the `examples` directory (e.g., `hello_world_glibc` or `hello_world_newlib` for C or `hello_world_interactive` for C++) and use that as a starting point.

**Writing completely from scratch**

If you want to write your app completely from scratch, first ensure that the SDK is working by compiling and running a few of the examples. Then a good next step is to look at the classes [pp::Module](https://developers.google.com/native-client/peppercpp/classpp_1_1_module) and [pp:Instance](https://developers.google.com/native-client/peppercpp/classpp_1_1_instance), which your app will need to implement.

On the HTML side, write a simple page with the `EMBED` element for the Native Client module. Then add the JavaScript event handlers for `loadstart`, `progress`, `error`, `abort`, `load`, `loadend`, and `message` and have the handlers write the event data to, e.g., the JavaScript console, so that it's possible to tell what went wrong if the Native Client module didn't load. The `load_progress` example shows how to do this.

Next, create the manifest file (`.nmf`). From `pepper_18` and onwards you can use the `generate_nmf.py` script found in the `tools/` directory for this. If you want to write it from scratch, the examples provide examples both for using `newlib` and `glibc` (the two Standard C librares currently supported). See `hello_world_newlib/` and `hello_world_glibc/`, respectively.

If you haven't used a gcc-family compiler before, it is also a good idea to look at the Makefile for some of the examples to see what compiler and linker flags to use. Compiling both for 32-bit and 64-bit right from the beginning is recommended.

Comment: The note about pepper_16 and pepper_17 was interesting, I will read more about that. However, them removing it for pepper_18 is interesting, there must be something they replaced it with

Comment: init_project.py generated build scripts for the old SCons build system. With Pepper 18 the build system was replaced by makefiles, and  given that using an example as a starting point was actually easier than using init_project.py, that script was removed rather than rewritten.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to follow the quick start doc at https://developers.google.com/native-client/pepper18/quick-start, in particular steps 5-7 of the tutorial ( https://developers.google.com/native-client/pepper18/devguide/tutorial ) which seems to be what you are asking about.